# Ibid. in LaTeX citations

Tags: latex

How can I get LaTeX to automatically use "Ibid." when two citations to the same source are made?

```
Here is a sentence with a citation.\footnote{\cite[p.~5]{Smith:1999}}
This sentence also has a citation.\footnote{\cite[p.~10]{Smith:1999}}
```

Desired:
Here is a sentence with a citation.[1]  This sentence also has a citation.[2]
...
1. Smith (1999), p. 5
2. Ibid., p. 10

Actual:
Here is a sentence with a citation.[1]  This sentence also has a citation.[2]
...
1. Smith (1999), p. 5
2. Smith (1999), p. 10

Answer (score 5):

You could look at biblatex, it seems to be more oriented to Humanities-style citations than bibtex is.  I'm pretty sure I got "ibid" working in it with no trouble.

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex

Answer (score 4):

One solution that worked for me, was to use the following:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
```

The style in my example will let the first citation be very verbose, and then afterwards only cite the author, title, and pages.

There are more styles with ibid., and these can be found at [this site](http://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Biblatex_citation_styles).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is [inlinebib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/inlinebib).